# ¿Cómo puedo evitar el Alert si ya guardé los cambios?, utilizando navigation.addListener('beforeRemove'

Tags: react-native, alertdialog, react-navigation, alert, useeffect

Necesitaría adaptar el siguiente código obtenido de React Navigation Docs (Snack), para **evitar el Alert si ya he "guardado los cambios" antes de intentar regresar a la página anterior** (por ejemplo si ya los he guardado a través de un botón, utilizando AsyncStorage.setItem). El código sólo detecta cambios en el campo text y mas allá de haber guardado o no previamente dichos cambios, *siempre genera el Alert cuando se pretende regresar*.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Alert, View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const EditTextScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);

  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        const action = e.data.action;
        if (!hasUnsavedChanges) {
          return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();

        Alert.alert(
          'Discard changes?',
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
          [
            { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
            {
              text: 'Discard',
              style: 'destructive',
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
            },
          ]
        );
      }),
    [hasUnsavedChanges, navigation]
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <TextInput
        autoFocus
        style={styles.input}
        value={text}
        placeholder="Type something…"
        onChangeText={setText}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.buttons}>
      <Button
        mode="contained"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('EditText')}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        Push EditText
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="EditText" component={EditTextScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  input: {
    margin: 8,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  buttons: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
  button: {
    margin: 8,
  },
});
```

Tal vez haya otro modo de hacerlo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

---

**.: SOLUCIÓN IMPLEMENTADA (06JUL2021) :.**
Finalmente he creado la siguiente función:

```
const statusNavigation = (statementArg, navigation)  => {
  navigation[statementArg]('beforeRemove', (e) => {
    const action = e.data.action;
    e.preventDefault();
    Alert.alert(
      '¿Descarta los cambios?',
      'Tiene cambios sin guardar. ¿Está seguro de descartarlos y regresar a la pantalla anterior?',
      [
        { text: "Permanecer", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
        {
          text: 'Descartar',
          style: 'destructive',
          onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
        },
      ]
    );
  });
};
```

Luego, simplemente llamo a la función desde donde la necesite y como la necesite:

```
flagModify ? StatusNavigation('removeListener', 'false') : StatusNavigation('addListener', 'true')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
//...

const EditTextScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);

  // Agregas el listener al editar el input
  const onEditingInput = (txt) => { 
    setText(txt);
    if(!editing) {
      setEditing(true);
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {...}
    }

  };
  // Al guardar borras el listener
  const onSave = () => {
    if(editing){
      setEditing(false);
      navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {...}
      navigation.navigate.goBack();
    }
  }
  //...
};
```

Comment: Inconveniente solucionado @Esteban, funciona a la perfección!. Muy agradecido. Quisiera optimizar el código, por ejemplo **navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {...} y navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {...}** podría escribirlo en una función que solo reciba el método addListener o removeListener como argumento, ya que el resto es igual. Entonces, dentro de la función, aplicaría navigation.<ARGUMENTO>('beforeRemove'...
El punto es que desconozco la sintaxis para reemplazar el método por el argumento recibido en la función..., ¿Sabés cómo?
Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Raul. Lo ideal para tal caso que comentas, es hacer una función, ej: `const beforeRemove = () => { ...aquí pegas todo el listener }`. Luego solo la llamas dentro de cada listener: 
`navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', beforeRemove());` y lo mismo para el **remove**. Así evitas duplicidad de código.

Comment: Sí Esteban, hice una función con el navigation incluído, quedó como quería. Ahora publico cómo lo resolví.